# how to define OR logic for an RPM dependency

Tags: redhat, rpm

I'm creating an RPM and I need to check that a version of Java 8 is installed on the machine.

The problem is that Oracle provides version-tied RPMs with names like `jdk1.8.0_45` and Redhat provides RPMs with names like `java-oracle-8`. I don't really care which one is installed, as long as one of them is installed, so how can I define `OR` condition logic on a Java 8? (Note this is for a RHEL5 or RHEL6 target, so new fangled features can't be used)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware RPM has no such functionality. You cannot declare a requirement like this.

That being said what RPM does have, and which is used as a rough equivalent to this, is the concept of "Provides".

Any package can `Provide: some_capability` and then other packages can `Require: some_capability` the same way they can `Require: <some_package>`.

You can also `Require: /some/file/path` if absolutely necessary (though avoid this whenever possible).

So, you need to compare the provided capabilities of the RPMs you care about and look for any common capability that you can depend on instead. Hopefully there's something in common there you can use. If there isn't then you are left with no choice other than to drop the requirement in your RPM and hope they have it and detect it at runtime (with a startup script perhaps).

(Technically you could also do a check during `%pre` and exit with a failure if you can't find java somewhere but I **strongly** recommend not doing that.)

Comment: thanks, that's helping me to confirm my suspicions. The problem is that I don't need `/usr/bin/java`, I need a specific version of Java installed *somewhere* on the system and the packages don't even agree about where that is.

Comment: The CentOS openjdk 1.7.0 packages provide `java7`, `jre7`, etc. (with version numbers if necessary). I assume the 1.8.0 packages do the same. Hopefully the various oracle packages provide something similar you can depend on.

Comment: nope, Oracle don't do that. Actually RHEL don't provide the `javaX` binaries either :-(

Comment: Can you show me the `rpm -qp --provides` output for the Oracle and RHEL java rpms you are interested in?

Comment: great! They both provide `java-1.8.0` which I can use :-)

Answer (score 2):

FYI - boolean logic in dependecy is called "Rich dependency" and is currently being introduce into RPM and will probably land in Fedora 24. See http://lists.rpm.org/pipermail/rpm-maint/2014-February/003666.html